# windows phone game of (480x800) to support other resolutions

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, windows-phone-8, screen-resolution

I have developed a xna game based on the resoltion 480x800, how can this game be targeted other resoltions like HD720P (720x1280) or WXGA (768x1280).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When running on Windows Phone 8 devices it will automatically be scaled by 150% or 160% (for 720P & WXGA) as appropriate.

As it's not possible to create XNA games that directly target WP8 you cannot create an XNA which uses the 16:9 aspect ratio and so you cannot make use of the full screen of a 720P device.

Comment: Thanks, how about the clarity of the game graphics. wouldnt be seems streatched ?

Comment: @Yogesh Potentially but it'll depend on the actual device and the size of the physical pixels. For the most part apps look Ok but it will depend on your graphics.